# Persist sidebar with fetched data through all the routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, routes, frontend

**Overview:**

I got this route in my react application

```
example.com/routeName/:id
```

This is the entrypoint for my users, they click on the link and see a screen with informations provided by this hash in a right sidebar component.

```
example.com/routeName/94a31bb9-e6ae-4e9a-8749-0807f9efd0001
```

Below I attached a kind of wireframe, trying to be more clear about the sidebar:

[Wireframe to understand how my app components are shown at the end, and why the hash is important in a visual way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkoVW.png)

This works fine, I can get the hash and make the request inside my dumb component to display data.

**The problem:**

I'm doing the fetch to the api in my Layout component, and ***passing down the data via props*** to my sidebar that is fixed in my layout, because it is displayed through all the user experience

When my user sign in, my route change, from:

```
example.com/routeName/94a31bb9-e6ae-4e9a-8749-0807f9efd0001
```

to:

```
example.com/nextRouteNameHere
```

I still see the component with the information I need, but if I refresh the page at the second route, the app crashes, because my sidebar cant find the hash to fetch my api and get the necessary data.

**What I've been trying to do:**

- Persist this route with the hash and make the route change internally - but that doesn't makes sense to me at all, and I could not find any resources even close to this strategy.
- Persist this hash in localstorage and get the hash with hooks inside the sidebar. This way if I can't find my hash at the url it'll be in the localstorage and I can fetch my api to get the data. I did it, but doesn't work because the components presents the some behavior, trying to render with no data.

  As I'm using redux to manage the global state I've already taken the hash and the fetch response to the localstorage, this way I can take this data through all the aplication, but the hash is what makes my hooks update when I tried to wrote this strategy, and when the user updates the page I got the same behavior, because the hook could not find the :id on the url.

**Final question**
How can I persist the sidebar with the fetched data I did when I load the page?

**NOTE**

I did not post the code because at this moment I got too much code trying to solve this and I'm stuck in this problem for almost one month. I'll update this post later on.

Comment: why you need to refresh the page going onto second route? refresh will empty all your states right

Comment: I don’t need to refresh the page, but I’m trying to avoid the app to break if my user does.